Can a FNaF Help Wanted 2 tag be created?
I was trying to post a question about the game Five Nights at Freddy’s: Help Wanted 2.
The tag for the preceding game is five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted, so I expected that adding -2 to the end would be the right tag: five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted-2.
But I got two errors:


The tag 'five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted-2' is too long; the maximum length is 35 characters.

Creating the new tag 'five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted-2' requires at least 300 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.



So, I ended up simply tagging it with the five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted. But I’d like to get this fixed.

Can someone please make a tag for Five Nights at Freddy’s: Help Wanted 2?
Calling it five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted-2 makes the most sense to me (if you can override the maximum length), but I would also accept fnaf-help-wanted-2 or something similar.

Unfortunately, we are bound to the 35 character limit on tags.  We cannot override that.
As for the reputation limitation, in cases where a user with < 300 reputation wants to ask about a game where no tag exists yet, usually a member of the community/moderator will gladly create one for you via an edit to your post.  Often, users will put something like "can someone create the tag for this game?" in their post, and someone will usually get around to it fairly quickly.
It looks like a member of our community already edited your post to add a relevant tag.  I think that tag will suffice, but I will also add a synonym to it for fnaf-help-wanted-2. As mentioned, I made
fnaf-help-wanted-2 the main tag since "FNAF" is a well known abbreviation for the game (and we have other tags for games in the series like this), and made five-nights-freddys-help-wanted-2 the synonym.

Actually I think I like [fnaf-help-wanted-2] better than [five-nights-freddys-help-wanted-2] (because it’s not missing the “at”).  Would you be able to swap the synonym and target please?

@ElementsInSpace "FNAF" is a generally known abbreviation for the game series, and we actually do have tags for some of the other games such as [tag:fnaf-sister-location] that use this format (also due to the tag length limit).  I am fine with swapping them.
